# as a Non-root-user,can I change DNS for me in linux?

Tags: dns

Environment is **redhat**

I **don't** have privilege

but now */etc/resolv.conf* is:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

Can I change my DNS just me, single user ?

How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean `/etc/resolv.conf` should be access by **ONLY** you ?

Comment: yes.  you can go pester whoever has root on the system to fix it.  or pester whoever runs the DHCP server to add a `domain-name-servers` option to their dhcp config.  Or both.  Be polite but insistent.  File a bug report or issue in their job/issue tracker (with luck, it won't be remedy but something decent instead).

Comment: cross posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366778/as-a-non-root-user-can-i-change-dns-for-me-in-linux

Comment: where are the other posts? the stackoverflow one is deleted

Answer (score 2):

Generally no.  However, there are special cases where you could make a program that uses `LD_PRELOAD` to pretend to the C runtime library that you have permission (and your own configuration).

This is mentioned in [Testing your software stack without root privileges using cwrap](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/05/05/testing-your-software-stack-without-root-privileges-using-cwrap/):

> The newest addition to the cwrap.org family so far is resolv_wrapper. This library makes it possible to test applications that use the libresolv API — a typical example would be a program that uses SRV DNS records to locate a server to connect to. This wrapper is diffent from nss_wrapper’s host support that wraps the NSS calls such as getaddrinfo(). In comparison, the resolv_wrapper support the libresolv low-level API.
>
> resolv_wrapper allows you to either set up a custom DNS server and point the test to this server with an environment variable or even set up a fake DNS database file that the application will use to construct test DNS replies. The first option is useful for testing DNS servers or integrated servers that include DNS, such as FreeIPA or Samba. The second option is more useful for testing clients where you need to test auto-discovery of services from a client.

The article continues by saying it will show a complete example (but it is only a fragment).  You may find a complete solution difficult to implement.

Comment: Yeah, It work .I edit the source of glibc (./resolv/resolv.h and ./nss/bug-erange.c),and compile and explort LD_PRELOAD = it , now I can have access to domain name  ^_^